# How to remove Extra(") from input Data in Jmeter

Tags: java, database, csv, jmeter, performance-testing

We are sending the input data by using Csv Data Config. In that Input data contains **""** (double-quoutes) Like:

> ("13115" INNOVATION ENGINEERING PROJECT OF SHAANXI PROVINCE).

But while executing the test it is passing with extra quotes("") like

> [""""13115" INNOVATION ENGINEERING PROJECT OF SHAANXI PROVINCE""""].

Could any help to find the solution for this

Comment: but what is the solution? what do you want? to remove the "" ??

Comment: did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

In CSV Data Set Config you need to set Allow Quoted Data = true

Sorry for the simple solution, but with true:

```
("13115" INNOVATION ENGINEERING PROJECT OF SHAANXI PROVINCE).
```

With false or edit ${}

```
"(""13115"" INNOVATION ENGINEERING PROJECT OF SHAANXI PROVINCE)."
```